# How can I use multiple projects in one sprint overview Azure boards

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to be able to have the issues and tasks of the different projects in Azure shown in one sprint planning overview.
We are with a small team but multipele projects. so we work on them simultaniouslly

Comment: Hi Azure devops does not have this feature yet. You can check out below workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Currently there is no direct way to show all the workitems across projects in one sprint planning overview.

You could merge all projects into one azure devops project and use area paths to differentiate them. Area paths is designed to allow you to group work items by team, product, or feature area. But you can also define different area path for each of the project to group the workitems from different projects. Please check the [document About area and iteration paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-areas-iterations?view=azure-devops), and document [Define area paths and assign to a team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

You can also define different team for each of the projects to differentiate them in one azure devops project(One team for one project). Please check the [document about Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/about-teams-and-settings?view=azure-devops), and the [tutorial to add a Team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Then you can view the workitems of different projects by filtering the area path or team in azure devops Boards, Backlogs and Sprints. Below screenshot for below example:

[image]

Another workaround which allows to view all the workitems across multiple project is to use Queries. check **Query across projects** shown as below screenshot.  Please check [tutorial Query across projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/using-queries?view=azure-devops#across-projects)

[image]